# Website strange font writing data:image/png;base64

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, base64

i have minify my js and css files, now i have the problem that my fonts have a strange form:

[image: font image error]

The Website loads, i see all correct. If the page have finish loading, all files are base64 codes.

What file is responsible for that? What can i do?
URL: http://goo.gl/2eZo0i

Thank all answers.

Comment: What file is responsible for styling/writing into that canvas?

Comment: im not sure. i have outsourcing this programming job. Some time ago. Cant watch this in firebug?